# Server monitoring powershell script

Tags: powershell, server, powershell-ise

I have written a PowerShell script for server monitoring. I have created a server on Google Cloud Platform. My server/Instance external IP is 34.72.154.186 (http://34.72.154.186/). This is my PowerShell script:

```
$content = Get-Content C:\Users\Samiddha\Desktop\ServerLists.txt
foreach ($line in $content)
{
    Test-Connection $line -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > ./junk
    if ($? -eq "True")
    {
        Write-Host "$line => OK"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$line => NOT-OK"
    }
}
```

This script returns the output `OK` when the server is running or up. When I stop the server by using `systemctl stop httpd` command, this script gives me the output `OK`, but why? It should give the output `NOT-OK`. But if I shutdown the server by clicking on the **STOP** button in Google Cloud dashboard, this script gives me the output `NOT-OK`. What modification of the script should I do, so that this script gives me the output `NOT-OK` when I stop the server by `systemctl stop httpd` command?

Comment: `$?` only indicates whether the previous command executed without error - if `Test-Connection` returns `$false` (because there's no response), `$?` will still be `$true`

Comment: Write `if( Test-Connection ... )` and remove `> ./junk`

Comment: I think you might want the `-Quiet` parameter rather than throwing away the output to `./junk`.  Then you can write `if ( Test-Connection $line -Quiet ) { ...`

Comment: @zett42 What I have to write in the `if` condition ? I wrote this `if (Test-Connection -eq "True")` but it returns error.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Still same problem

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So, what modification I have to do ?

Comment: @SanniddhaChakrabarti because `Test-Connection -Quiet` returns a bool, it doesn't need to be compared (i.e. `-eq 'True'` is unnecessary). Your example doesn't appear to include the `-Quiet` parameter anyway.

I believe `$?` is returning `true` because `> .\junk` is succeeding. If you don't care about errors, use `-ErrorAction Ignore`. If you need to handle the errors, use `-ErrorAction Stop` and put the statement in a try/catch block.

Comment: In addition to what everyone said previously, I might be wrong but, `systemctl stop httpd` means Apache will not be running on the server, which does not mean that the server will be unresponsive to ping.

Comment: There is a difference between stopping the server in Google Cloud dashboard, which means, turning off the server and stopping the HTTP service (Apache). If you actually want to check if HTTP service is running, the right cmdlet for this is probably `Test-NetConnection`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon still same problem. `Test-NetConnection`  gives the status `OK` even if the sever is down.

Comment: @Stroniax if I remove `> ./junk` it also gives the status `OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my attempt.

```
    $content = Get-Content C:\Users\Samiddha\Desktop\ServerLists.txt
    foreach ($line in $content){
      if (Test-Connection $line -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Host "$line => OK"
      }else{
        Write-Host "$line => NOT-OK"
      }
    }
```

screen output

```
    PS C:\Users\Tech\desktop\i-net> .\test
    192.168.43.38 => OK
    192.168.43.37 => NOT-OK
    34.72.154.186 => NOT-OK
    PS C:\Users\Tech\desktop\i-net>
```

first Ip is my server
Second is nothing
third was your supplied ip. i guess it was not up

You could also add -ForegroundColor Red to the end of line 8 and it will make the down servers pop out visually. ie

```
    Write-Host "$line => NOT-OK" -ForegroundColor Red
```